How can I configure OpenSSH to forward SFTP-Requests?
I have a two-server setup in which one is only reachable via the other. The corresponding client config looks like this:
Host <actual_host>
    User root
    ProxyCommand /bin/bash -c "ssh root@<jump_host> -W [%h]:%p"

I want to setup SFTP for a dedicated user on <actual_host>, but enable them to run sftp-requests against <jump_host> without having to change their local configuration. Basically, for the user it should look as if the sftp-folders are on <jump_host>, when in fact they are on <actual_host>.
Right now I can successfully run sftp <user>@<actual_host> on <jump_host>, but not sftp <user>@<jump_host>.
My idea was to use Match directives to match this dedicated user and then use ForceCommand to forward them to <actual_host>. Something like this:
Match User <user>
    ForceCommand ssh -W %h:%p <actual_host>

But this results in Too many authentication failures and a closed connection.
How would I need to configure the <jump_host> to enable the behaviour I'm looking for?

All I can add here is that SFTP over OpenSSH requires that root has sole ownership of the ChrootDirectory (sshd_config).

Yes, it needs to be some form of ForceCommand ssh <actual_host>, so you must get the "second step" authentication dealt with first. The error message you're getting is normal at this point.
The client's original credentials won't be passed through by default (the options for that are entirely client-controlled), so if you cannot assume that the client will have SSH agent forwarding (or Kerberos delegation) enabled, then the proxy_host needs to have a private key stored in the user's ~/.ssh/id_xxx that would give it passwordless access to the actual_host. Alternatively, "Hostbased" authentication can be suitable for this setup (it would use the proxy_host's host keys rather than user keys to provide a seamless connection).
As for the specific command, however, -W %h:%p makes no sense in this context – for one, the %h:%p are not going to be expanded to anything (the ProxyCommand context expands them because its specific goal is to connect to some host:port; the ForceCommand context has nothing like that, as the user is already connected); and there is no useful host:port to specify here anyway, because the SFTP server doesn't listen on any TCP port.
Instead, the SFTP server is usually invoked as a command; the SFTP client runs the "sftp" subsystem by doing ssh -s <host> sftp (the -s option requests a subsystem alias instead of a regular command), and that's what your ForceCommand should imitate:
Match User <user>
    ForceCommand ssh <actual_host> -s sftp


Aside:
Internally, SSH subsystems simply run whatever command is specified in the corresponding Subsystem line (for OpenSSH, that is), so if your actual_server has this in its sshd_config:
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

then, for the sake of an example, you could also call it like this:
Match User <user>
    ForceCommand ssh <actual_host> /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server

although this would be unnecessarily OpenSSH-specific (and even distro-specific), so unless you need to pass some custom options to sftp-server, you should generally stick with the -s subsystem invocation.

Aside 2:
Your original client config should really just look like this:
Host <actual_host>
    User root
    ProxyJump root@<jump_host>

(but preferably with a non-root account on the jump_host!)

I can access the <actual_host> from the <jump_host> with ssh <actual_host>, have configured ForceCommand ssh <actual_host> -s sftp and have restarted sshd. However, when running sftp <user>@<jump_host> I still get Too many authentication failures. Any idea what else I might be missing?

First, which host do you get that from – the jump_host or the actual_host? Run a manual connection using ssh <user>@<jump_host> -v -v -s sftp the way that an SFTP client does, and verify that you can authenticate to the jump_host itself first. (Which, at this point, has nothing to do with ForceCommand yet.)

Does that mean that I need to create the SFTP-User on the <actual_host> and the <jump_host>? I was hoping that I could configure the <jump_host> to just pass on the requests.
To answer your question: The authentication failures response comes from the <jump_host>.

It doesn't have to be the same user, but it needs to be some user that the jump_host could use to connect to the actual_host – and which would have the privileges to actually operate on the files! No matter what way you do it, the SFTP requests are going to operate on files owned by some user, so I'd assume the actual_server already has an account that you could use here.

<actual_host> has an account  that can operate on the files - when I'm on the jumphost, I can execute sftp <user>@<acutual_host> successfully (after entering my password).
But I don't want to give any account on <jump_host> privileges to operate on the files. My thought was that <jump_host> would just pass the request on, and the client would then authenticate with the <actual_host>.
Is this not possible? Would it always be an account from <jump_host> that needs the privileges to edit files on <actual_host>?

No, it is not possible if you want <jump_host> to do this for a specific user. SFTP does not have its own authentication of any form – it relies entirely on the SSH connection doing that. But if <jump_host> were to forward the SSH requests to <actual_host>, it wouldn't be able to see what's in them; the requests are encrypted and it wasn't party to the SSH key exchange, so there's no way for it to Match against the username. And if <jump_host> does the key exchange with the client, then it cannot forward public-key user auth requests as they're cryptographically bound to the key exchange.

On the other hand,  if <jump_host> accepts both the key exchange and the user authentication in order to learn the username, then there is no other authentication request left to "pass on" to <actual_host> anymore (the same request cannot be forwarded to another connection) – the <jump_host> would have to make its own SSH auth requests with its own private key (which is the option described in my post, and which you've already ruled out). So it's pretty much impossible for <proxy_host> to match the username and "pass through" everything else without ending up in a privileged position.

(In other words, you could say that SSHv2 was designed to prevent someone from doing what you're trying to do.)

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
